# Can you put multiple elements in an html <a> tag?

Tags: php, html

Is there any way to create a new a href that remembers all the submitted data earlier. I don't know how to say it properly so I will describe in the code:

The first button

```
<a href="thesamefile.php?n1='.$data_from_db['id'].'"> Click me </a>
```

After the user clicks it, he is redirected to the same page but with the new button :

```
<a href="thesamefile.php?n1='.$GET the same as before data?...['id'].'&n2='.$data_from_db['id'].'"> Click me </a>
```

And so on :

```
<a href="thesamefile.php?n1='.$GET the same as before data?....['id'].'&n2='.$data_from_db['id'].'&n3='.$data_from_db['id'].'"> Click me </a>
```

How do i create the n variable to be added and increased after the button is pressed ?

( I have a table displayed from a database by using the while command with  `mysqli_fetch_array($database);` )

The table is created like (trivial ) :
   $retrieve_items = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id > 0");

```
$col = 0; 
echo '<table width=100% border= 1><tr>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $retrieve_items )) {
$col ++;
echo '<td>'.$row['name_item'].'</td>';

 if ($col % 5 == 0 )
   {
    echo '</tr><tr>';

     }
  }

 echo '</tr></table>';
```

Comment: it's called a query string. `<a href="test.php?k1=v1&k2=v2&k3=v3&etc...">` You can stick whatever you want in there, subject to knowing that most servers and browsers will limit URL lengths and silently chop off anything that goes past the limit.

Comment: To remember information the user submitted across multiple pages, it might be more appropriate to use either `$_COOKIE` or `$_SESSION` (session if the user shouldn't tamper with the data / should only see it all at the end of his session, etc.) What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @AurelBílý i want to make some interactive buttons for the user . When he clicks one he 'tehnically ' selects the first item, then the item should turn blue, when he selects the second one , the user should see on his refreshed page 2 blue items selected. something like that

Comment: I see. Is it necessary to refresh the page every time? Would a client-side solution work? I.e. JavaScript or HTML+CSS?

Comment: @AurelBílý that was my first option but my knowledge in using them is....very...low ...so... I advance to plan B (this one with the refreshing option )

Comment: This could be a classic xy-problem. What is the full plan? You have just rows of IDs from a database? They are put as single values into an array? What is the `<form>` in HTML? Checkboxes? The naming convention hasn't necessarily to be `n1, n2...`? There might be better approaches.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone the full plan is to create a table with randoms id's loaded from database. The user can select any of them and submit them further . In this moments this is just a table ( no formus or other things )

Comment: What is you code so far to generate a table with `<input>` elements (or links or anything else)? Please click "edit" below your question and add your code snippet.

Comment: updated in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend not to try managing numbered variable names. If there is no important reason to do so, it will make your logic unnecessarily complicated.

PHP understands array parameters in e.g. `$_GET`. They are passed from HTML with empty braces appended to the parameter name.

This is a little demo to illustrate this alternative approach:

```
<?php
// get the passed array or generate a new one
$n = isset($_GET['n']) ? (array) $_GET['n'] : [];

//ppend 2 random numbers
$n[] = rand(1,100);
$n[] = rand(1,100);

//output the link with GET parameters in query
?>
<a href="?n[]=<?php echo implode('&n[]=', $n) ?>">the link</a>

<!-- or let PHP's built-in generate a propper query --><br>
<a href="?<?php echo http_build_query(['n' => $n]); ?>">the link</a>
```

Be aware, that the second link generated by `http_build_query` contains indexes of the array, which are commonly based on 0.

Answer (score 0):

in php, to access the current query String, you can use

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```

so you could so something like

```
<a href="thesamefile.php?<?php echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ?>&othervalue=123"> Click me </a>
```

or you could replace your previous value in the query string

Comment: You need `?` before the query string.